# ANTLR4: have parser rule match token wildcards

Tags: antlr4

I am working on a grammar that allows for keywords as identifiers, and the current suggestion seems to be to do something like:

```
id : 'if'|'call'|'then'|ID;
```

My language has a lot of keywords, so I've been doing:

```
id: ~(PLUS | MINUS);
```

Basically any token that's NOT a non-keyword token.

Is there a way to have all of my keyword tokens be prepended with some string and wildcard match that? e.g.

```
K_PLUS: '+';
K_MINUS: '-';
ID: <everything else>;

id : ID | ~(K_*);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a technical/scientific reason why something like that isn't allowed?

Comment: @ArunRamani ah, missed your question. Well, I think it's not supported because it is not very often needed. Also, it's rather error prone: when adding rules, you'd accidentally match it by some wild card matching. Even if it was supported, I'd still use  `id : 'if'|'call'|'then'|ID;` instead of `id : ID | ~(K_*);`